# Connection Load Balancing feature on OpenWRT

Tags: openwrt, openwisp

i'm a newbie with OpenWRT, and i'm working on OpenWRT project that has a Connection Load Balance feature: "when there are more than one access point (AP) in the network, network administrator may set up AP Load Balance to prevent that one of the AP gets overloaded, while others are still quite free. This help improve the Wi-Fi performance for all the wireless clients" (like Drayteks' APs). And I wonder if OpenWRT can support this feature? If not, can you tell me if any opensource software can do that (like OpenWiSP,...)? Thanks for your help and I appologize in advance for my English.

Comment: as far as I know, there's no open source solution to accomplish this. If you really need this, you may contribute to OpenWISP so that this feature can be gradually introduced in future releases